Error when retrieving database data with Netlify when using mobile device
Created a very basic app with a PostgreSQL database hosted on Render. The app works as it should if accessed via a desktop browser, but cannot retieve the database data when accessed via a mobile device.
https://sdstockdb.netlify.app/
Did a screenshot of mobile debug (see attached). Comes back with a 'Connection Refused' error, but it works correctly on the desktop?
I tried fetching with the URL as well, but it doesnt help:
// Fetch items from the backend
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/items")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setItems(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching data:", error));
  }, []);

I cannot see why it should be different for a mobile device. I get the error when the mobile device is connected to the same network as the desktop (while the desktop works fine), as well as when the mobile device is on mobile data.
Any suggesstions would be appreciated.
Thanks
Tried the following:

changing the getch URL
different bobile devices
using dieffernt networks


I don't see how http://localhost:5000/api/items will work on a remote device.

Thinking about it. you are absolutely correct. It does not work. It worked with localhost on the desktop because I do have a local database running on it. My apologies.

I work at Render.
I do see your application working on mobile, and looks like you were able to solve the problem.
This isn't part of your question, but if you host your frontend at Render, you'll have less latency between your frontend and backend being in the same private cloud, and won't have to deal with being billed for outgoing traffic for these two services to communicate. Right now, Netlify and Render will both be tracking all outgoing traffic, from Netlify to Render, and back from Render to Netlify, and that could add up if your application gets busy. At Render, if you host your frontend and backend together, even as separate services, we won't charge bandwidth fees for the apps to communicate.
